# Zsh script syntax issue

Tags: zsh

I've honestly worn out my keyboard on this one... what does the (N) term in the following script segment mean? (from oh-my-zsh.sh):

```
for config_file ($ZSH_CUSTOM/*.zsh(N)); do
  source $config_file
done
```

I ask because .zsh files in $ZSH_CUSTOM directory aren't getting sourced. Thanks for any insights!

Comment: So... are you using zsh or bash?

Comment: does using shell debug/trace with `set -vx` show you anything useful? AND add an `echo "config_file=$config_file"` . Good luck.

Comment: Using zsh. echo of course identified the files - and I found I'd not added alias commands in the files (that's all they are doing). Pardon the stupidity, thanks for the answer!

Comment: Just to be explicit, I edited out any mention of Bash. The syntax you are trying to use is exclusive to Zsh and this has nothing to do with Bash at all.

Comment: First try `echo $ZSH_CUSTOM`, if it returns empty you can set it on `~/.zshenv` like this: `export $ZSH_CUSTOM="/your/zshenv/file".

Comment: Thank you all for your comments!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The *(N)* is a glob qualifier. From the man:

> N sets the NULL_GLOB option for the current pattern

It means:

> If a pattern for filename generation has no matches, delete the
>   pattern from the argument list instead of reporting an error.

So, it implies only one thing: if you do not have any zsh script in $ZSH_CUSTOM the loop won't run instead of reporting an error.

Comment: No problem. It is not really easy to find it when you don't know what you are dealing with.